# with google files list how can I only show my owned folder instead of shared ones?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

I only want to show my owned files when use the following code, but actually it list all the files even those share with me. how can I prevent this happen please

```
   gapi.client.drive.files
      .list({
        includeItemsFromAllDrives: false,
        supportsAllDrives: false,
        pageSize: 10,
        fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, modifiedTime)',
        q: searchTerm
      })
```

Comment: What is the content of searchTerm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [search term](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms#drive_properties) you should be using is owners. specifically the email address of the user how you are after as owner

```
'XXX@gmail.com' in owners
```

Or if you are looking for the currently authenticated user then use

```
'me' in owners
```

To find folders you would use the following which basically checks for the mime type of a folder.

```
mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
```

Then to string them both together you just use and

Example

```
   gapi.client.drive.files
      .list({
        includeItemsFromAllDrives: false,
        supportsAllDrives: false,
        pageSize: 10,
        fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, modifiedTime)',
        q: ''me' in owners and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder''
      })
```

You need to fix the '' around the me im not very experienced with javascript sorry.